# Showing a JSON file at a specific URL in Gatsbyjs

Tags: reactjs, json, gatsby, apple-app-site-associate, apple-app-site-association

I'm trying to [link my iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains) to a Gatsby website but I can't find how to show the following JSON file at a specific URL in my Gatsby website

I've added the JSON file inside my Static Folder

[image: VsCode Folders Screen Shot]

```
{
    "applinks":{
       "apps":[
          
       ],
       "details":[
          {
             "appID":"XXX.com.XXX.XXXX",
             "paths":[
                "*"
             ]
          }
       ]
    },
    "webcredentials":{
       "apps":[
          "XXXX.com.XXXX.XXXXX"
       ]
    }
 }
```

and I would now like it to show it up at this URL : `mydomain.org/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`

Answer (score 1):

The file should be at:

```
https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association.json
```

According to the structure of the static folder.

Because Gatsby clones the internal structure, and because the file it's a JSON extension (`.json`) the internal folder structure of the static folder becomes the path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use static folder to add static file, here the steps

- Add static folder on root project (inline with package.json)
- Inside it add folder .well-known and your json file in it
- then you can open it by "base url"/.well-known/assetlinks.json
  [image]